# jQuery: Fastest way to load and use a big XML file

Tags: jquery, html, xml, json, jquery-xml

I have a quite big XML file (around 5MB) and need to load that with jQuery. Afterwards, I would like to query and display some data in my html file (I am thinking about a similar way to do that as .NET/C# provides it).

What is the fastest way to load such a big file?

Would it be a good approach to convert the xml file to a json object (with [this](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) plugin?

Comment: I don't understand why you would store 5 megabytes of data in a browsers memory anyway. They're really not designed for this. Why don't you have the server handle more of the processing / querying?

Comment: I would have preferred to have a server too, but unfortunately, it is a company's requirement

Comment: That really doesn't make a difference. There are proper and improper ways to use the technologies that are available today. Browsers aren't designed to handle this kind of thing and it will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use JSON instead of XML
2. If you are loading a Tree, you can make use of the "Lazy Loading" principle

Comment: thanks a lot :-) is there a plugin which provides Lazy Loading?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to *not* load the entire file before you start processing; open the file on demand so that, for all practical purposes, it's ready for use by the user, then load it in parts, either buffered so it will all load in time anyway, or as required so that it will all load with use anyway.